# Fibonnaci Sequence order with two input

Tags: java

I need to do the following :

- Write an algorithm which would be able to get two input numbers, n and P and process the
  following requirements:

  - (a) If the first three Fibonacci numbers are given as 1, 1 and 2, then what is the n-th
    number? Find the number value.
  - (b)If the first three Fibonacci numbers are given as x1 = 1, x2 = 1 and x3 = 2, then what is
    the least value of n for which xn > P? Find the n value.

```
public static void fib(int n)
{
    if(n < 0)
        System.out.print("0");
    else
    {
         int f0 = 0;
         int f1 = 1;
         System.out.print(f0 + ", " + f1);
         while(n >= f1)
         {
             int temp = f0 + f1;
             f0 = f1;
             f1 = temp;
             System.out.print(", " + f1);
         }
     }
}


static void main(String[] args){

    fib(6);

}
```

Answer

> 0 1 1 2 3 5

Did i met the following criteria?

Comment: You can [calculate the n-th number](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibFormula.html) right away, no need for iteration.

Comment: @AlexR, but i'm trying to figure out what is P due to this criteria, n and P and process

Comment: Where did you get that question from? Are you sure your wording is correct? It doesn't even say what `n` and `P` should be.

Comment: @AlexR, i posted the full question. I'm trying to figure it out myself too.. first time i myself am blur

Comment: So are you basically trying to find the smallest nth Fibonacci term which is greater than the number P? Also, in your call `fib(6)`, is P=6?

Comment: @RachayitaGiri, yes . I think i should also put n if not mistaken as the input. correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: If you need to calculate n yourself, it wouldn't make sense to take it as input. All you need is P.